# How start cron task

Tags: server, cron

I use `crontab -e` and ent add new test task

```
0 0 * * * /etc/webmin/fsdump/backup.pl 90881498558004
* * * * * cd /var/www/partners.dev/ && .bin/drush cron --root=web
* * * * * cd /var/www/partners.test/ && .bin/drush cron --root=web
*/1 * * * * /scripts/test.sh
```

code test.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

LOG_DIR=/var/log/script_backup/;
LOG_NAME=crone.log;
NOW=$(date +'%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S');

function write_log(){
    mkdir -p ${LOG_DIR};
    sudo sh -c "echo '$1' >> $LOG_DIR$LOG_NAME"
}

write_log ${NOW};
```

I am ex command `sudo service cron restart`, but file crone.log is empty.

Comment: Your script uses `sudo`. Who enters the password?

Comment: @PerlDuck password is not necessary

Comment: Is your user allowed to create the directory below `/var`?

Comment: You're trying to write $1 to the log file.  $1 is the command line argument to the script.  Crontab shouldn't provide one of those.

Comment: @RobotHumans `$1 == $(date +'%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S')`

Comment: @SanychGoilo: You do not need to restart cron service after adding something with `crontab -e`; `*/1` is the same as `*`; Your use of `sudo` is very strange ... Please tell us what you're trying to do, I feel like this is an [XY-Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: If that's what you want, you want something more like this: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/D6RVZMKPYG/

Comment: @PerlDuck user can create files and folder. test.sh is true work

Comment: you say user can create files and folders, but why then do you use `sudo` to create the file... ? It doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: Is test.sh executable? --> `chmod u+x /scripts/test.sh`

Answer (score 3):

You're executing a shell script, so that `sh` should be used in front of the script file name.

Replace this line in your crontab

```
*/1 * * * * /scripts/test.sh
```

with this line

```
*/1 * * * * sh /scripts/test.sh
```

Comment: Good point... If test.sh is executable, you would not need that, but if it is not executable that could indeed be the issue and your answer would fix that. But like the shebang states, he wants `bash` instead of `sh`.

Comment: i deleted `sudo` in `sudo sh -c "echo '$1' >> $LOG_DIR$LOG_NAME"` and edit to */1 * * * * bash /scripts/test.sh. it helped me.